# Random selection of a number from an array to put it in another array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am writing code for a project in Java and i need to select a number from the array `int [] numbers={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`  and take the selected number and put it into another array but in the index - 1 of the second array..because i want the input on the second array to be like a human put that number there..For example, I want it to be in the position with index 5 not 6 (because the computer counts for 0 but we don't).
The code i am writing is : `int rndNumb = rnd.nextInt(numbers.length) - 1` , but it doesn't seem to work...(rnd is my random class object).

Comment: What is your actual question? "*I am writing code for a project*" - How about showing us your code? Without the code, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `Random rnd = new Random();` So the problem is that `nextInt(length) - 1` will return a value between `-1` and `length` -> Consider removing the minus one that you have added to `nextInt()` function result.

From `Random.nextInt()` documentation, you can see that:

> ```
>  * @return the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed {@code int}
>  *         value between zero (inclusive) and {@code bound} (exclusive)
>  *         from this random number generator's sequence
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.random() , this return a random double from 0 to 1 (including zero, but not including 1). 
Then you can multiply this number by 10 (or the size of your array). 
Then cast this into Integer (this will round it down, meaning get rid of the decimal). Then you can use this number to get the int at that index in your array. Here is the code:

```
    int[] numbersArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int[] randomNumberArray = new int[1];
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    randomNumberArray[0] = numbersArray[randomNumber];
    System.out.println(randomNumberArray[0]);
```

This will generate a random number from 0 to 9 which in turn will give you a number from your array from 1 to 10 (since the array index start at 0).

As for the second part of your question, can you clarify a bit more? Arrays always start from 0, so if you want your number to be stored at index 1, just put some random number in the index 0. That is the way the arrays work.